# What do I use in place of sudo su to become root?

Tags: command-line, sudo

After I open a terminal, I run `sudo su`. But it then gives me

```
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 27 <<< sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 27 sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I tried running `su` and then input the password but the terminal closes after a few seconds. What command do I use to become root? Also, I'm on Ubuntu 18.

Comment: Which Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.

Comment: 18.04 or 18.10?

Comment: Also please explain what you did. Using `visudo` to edit sudoers has a check for invalid edits to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 2):

Boot from a live session, edit `/etc/sudoers` and fix the mistake.

An example on how to do that from a live session (change `sda1` to what you need it to be and if you use another mount point also change below to what you used):

```
sudo mount -o rw,remount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo visudo -f /mnt/etc/sudoers
```

and then fix line 27.

Comment: Honest question: would a recovery mode root shell suffice for this?

Comment: Yes but I consider that more difficult so opted for this method. I also assume we all always have a live session at hand  ;-)